# Потоки и их выполнение в телеграмм боте python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, многопоточность, threading

Я пишу бота для телеги который будет регистрировать пользователя и отправлять ему открытку на день рождения. Суть в том, что рекомендации которые я нашел содержат функцию:

```
def everyday():
    schedule.every().day.at("10:21").do(check_birthday)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(60)
```

и она выполняет свою работу но кроме нее не выполняется регистрация. Т.Е. если я запущу бота, он поздравит меня во время но до тех пор никто не может пройти регистрацию и воспользоваться другими кнопками, они просто не выводят свой функционал. Думал создать поток в котором функция будет работать обособлено но я новичок и скорее всего сделал это неправильно, хотя работа выполняется но все так же остальные кнопки не работают:

```
Potok1 = threading.Thread(target= everyday)
Potok1.start()
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что я мог упустить, заранее спасибо!
p.s.
Еще я думал сделать несколько потоков для остальных функций но ничего не поменялось, выглядит это так:

```
Potok1 = threading.Thread(target= everyday)
Potok1.start()

Potok2 = threading.Thread(target = start(message))
Potok2.start()

Potok3 = threading.Thread(target= check_text(message))
Potok3.start()
```

Comment: И одного хватит запускать вместе основным потоком. schedule.every() перенести в функцию регистраций

Comment: функция не выполняется в таком виде к сожалению, да и как она должна выполняться если функция регистрации вызывается лишь на время, может я чего то не понимаю но она же должна вызваться исполниться и завершиться. Исходя из этого логично что функция не была выполнена

Comment: При регистрации, если функция содержит `while True`, она будет выполняться постоянно, пока каким-то явным способом не завершить функцию.

Comment: @Хуавейнова, если как по вашей логике, то бот вообще никак не сможет работать, ведб ему надо постоянно и бесперерывно опрашивать сервер.

Comment: Вы правы, это я упустил, внес функцию проверки даты в команду старт и совсем забыл что я к ней не обращаюсь в принципе! после активации она стала работать, но все таки эта функция будет работать только после ввода команды а именно при запуске бота что бы она начала работу самостоятельно можно ли что то придумать?

Comment: при запуске этой функции в основном потоке, бот перестает обрабатывать команды @bot.message_handler которые отвечают за регистрацию и прочее. после получения поздравления в указанное время ситуация не меняется. все так же кнопки не активны.

Answer (score 0):

```
# настройки бота. основной поток

def sch_every(time):
    schedule.every().day.at(time).do(check_birthday)

# доп. поток
def everyday():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(60)

threading.Thread(target= everyday).start()
# запуск бота
```